# Override the original record while creating a new one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :ceo, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Ceo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

c = Company.find(1)
c.create_ceo(:name => "Jobless", :age => 46, :gender => "male") # This will create a new CEO named "Jobless"
c.create_ceo(:name => "Baldmer", :age => 56, :gender => "male") # This will create a new CEO named "Baldmer"
```

Once the 2nd CEO created, the first CEO's company_id is set to be nil, how could I remove the 1st CEO from the db once the 2nd one is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:dependent => :destroy` doesn't destroy the old Ceo record when a new value is assigned. All that does is destroy the Ceo object, **in the event that the Company object is destroyed**.

If you're simply changing Ceo's you can either change the fields on the existing Ceo record:

```
c.ceo.name = "Baldmer"
c.ceo.age = 56
c.ceo.save
# This doesn't create a new record, it simply changes the only already in place
```

Or the following, which both changes the attributes, and saves the record in one shot.

```
c.ceo.update_attributes({:name => "Baldmer", :age => 56, :gender => "male"})
```

Or explicitly destroy the **old** Ceo record after the new one is created:

```
c = Company.find(1)
jobless = c.create_ceo(:name => "Jobless", :age => 46, :gender => "male")
baldmer = c.create_ceo(:name => "Baldmer", :age => 56, :gender => "male")

jobless.destroy     # you need to explicitly destroy this Ceo record.
```

On a side note, if you stay with what you've got, and you're interested in getting a list of CEOs that are in the DB, but which are not currently working for companies, you could do:

```
 > ceos_without_companys = Ceo.find(:all, :conditions => ":company_id = nil")
=> ["<#Ceo, :name => "Jobless", :age => 46, :gender => "male">]
```

Comment: thats right. In the first case, you could use `c.ceo.update_attributes` .I would further recommend, in the second case, to wrap this in a transaction to make sure your DB stays coherent. see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html.

Comment: @normalocity, thanks a lot, I'd like to know if there's a built-in mechanism with which the original CEO will be deleted automatically while the COMPANY is assigned a new one

Comment: You can use the `:before_save` callback on ActiveRecord objects to check to see if the CEO is about to change (i.e. if it's in the list of attributes that are about to be saved, and it's not the same as the old CEO). If the CEO *is* about to change, then you use that to trigger the destruction of the old record. (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). I'm afraid there's no "read my mind", automatic solution to this one. You're going to have to give ActiveRecord a hint somewhere of how you want to handle things.

Comment: One more note, however, before you destroy the old CEO object, make sure you check the validity of the new attributes (`Ceo.valid?`) otherwise you might get an invalid CEO object coming in, destroy the old object, and when the new CEO object fails validation your company will be left with no CEO at all. :(

Comment: @normalocity,thanks a lot for the replies, i guess i have to destroy the previous CEO in a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :ceo, :dependent => :destroy

  def assign_ceo options ={}
    Company.transaction do
      ceo.try(:destroy)
      create_ceo(options)
    end
  end
end
```

Now:

```
company.assign_ceo(:name => "Foo", ...)
```

Comment: so, there's no such a built-in mechanism with which the original CEO will be deleted automatically while the COMPANY is assigned a new one